# JMS serialisation listener: added objects are empty

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I am building Symfony3 project. I am using JMS for serialisation. I have `Group` entity with ManyToMany relationship to `User`. I am trying to add additional data to `Group` objects. I am using serialisation listener to achieve this. For example, I want to get group members for that group who went to same school as current user. I `setData` to group object like this:

```
class SerializationListener{

    //Constructor
    /**
     * @param ObjectEvent $event
     */
    public function onGroupEntitySerialize(ObjectEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$this->currentUser) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var GenericSerializationVisitor $visitor */
        $visitor = $event->getVisitor();

        $group = $event->getObject();

        $groupMembersFromUserSchool = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
        ->groupMembersFromUserSchool($group, $this->currentUser);

        $visitor->setData('members', $groupMembersFromUserSchool);

        $groupMembersCountFromUserSchool = count($groupMembersFromUserSchool);

        $visitor->setData('memberCount', $groupMembersCountFromUserSchool);
    }
}
```

However, I get this as result:

```
 {
"items": [
    {
        "memberCount": 17,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "TestGroup1",
        "members": [
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {}
        ]
    }
   ]
  }
```

So user details in `members` property are hidden. How do I display them?

```
  class Group{

        /**
         * @Expose()
         * @Groups({"group-details", "group-list"})
         */
         protected $members;
  }

  class User{
        /**
         * @Expose()
         * @Groups({"group-details", "group-list"})
         */
         private $id;

        /**
         * @Expose()
         * @Groups({"group-details", "group-list"})
         */
         protected $name;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the doc of the [source code here](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/src/JMS/Serializer/GenericSerializationVisitor.php#L178) you can only add `integer|float|boolean|string|array` value:

```
/**
 * Allows you to add additional data to the current object/root element.
 * @deprecated use setData instead
 * @param string $key
 * @param integer|float|boolean|string|array|null $value This value must either be a regular scalar, or an array.
 *                                                       It must not contain any objects anymore.
 */
public function addData($key, $value)
{
    if (isset($this->data[$key])) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('There is already data for "%s".', $key));
    }
```

So try something like:

```
    $arrayValuesOfMembers = // some data as array probably extracted by the repo methods
    $visitor->setData('members', $arrayValuesOfMembers);
```

Hope this help

Comment: this explains why I couldn't display object. thanks. I tried to get results with getArrayResults() in user repo. however, i need to get objects, not nested arrays in members list. therefore I realised this is not best solution for me